# Post JSON value without ajax

Tags: javascript, json

I have a simple HTML form which collects four different values. I would like to post the collected data to an API server in JSON format.

```html
<body>
<h2>Form</h2>

<form action="/endpoints" method="post" onsubmit="return profile();">

MAC Address:<input type="text" id="mac" name="mac" size="12"/> 

<br/>Select Catagory:<br/>
<select name="catagory" id="catagory">
<option value="SmartDevice">SmartDevice</option>
<option value="Printer">Printer</option>
<option value="Printer">Printer</option>
</select>
<br/>Select Family:<br/>
<select name="family" id="family">
<option value="Android">Android</option>
<option value="Ricoh">Ricoh</option>
<option value="Canon">Canon</option>
</select>
<br/>Name:<br/>
<select name="name" id="name">
<option value="Android">Android</option>
<option value="Ricoh Multifunction Printer">Ricoh Multifunction Printer</option>
<option value="Canon Printer">Canon Printer</option>
</select>


<input type="submit" style="width: 200px;" id="submit" onclick="return profile();">

<script type="text/javascript">
{literal}
function profile (){
var addr = document.getElementsByName("mac")[0].value;
var str_array = addr.split(',');
var nam = document.getElementsByName("name")[0].value;
var famil = document.getElementsByName("family")[0].value;
var catagor = document.getElementsByName("catagory")[0].value;
for(var i = 0; i < str_array.length; i++) {
   str_array[i] = str_array[i].replace(/^\s*/, "").replace(/\s*$/, "");
   var output = '[' + JSON.stringify({mac: str_array[i], device: {category: catagor, family: famil, name: nam}}) + ']';
};
return output;
}
{/literal}
</script>
</form>
</body>
```

I am able to get the desired JSON output if I call profile (); in the console. But Posted data is different with all values in single line.

I expect the post data to be like:

```js
[{"mac": "aabbccddeeff", "device": {"category": "Printer", "family": "Xerox", "name": "Xerox WorkCenter"}},
 {"mac": "bbccddeeffaa", "device": {"category": "Printer", "family": "Xerox", "name": "Xerox WorkCenter"}},
 {"mac": "ccddeeffaabb", "device": {"category": "Printer", "family": "Xerox", "name": "Xerox WorkCenter"}}]'
```

Please help me and I am a newbie. :-)

Comment: Added note when I call for the profile(); it only displays the last mac and not the complete mac.

Comment: You can't change post data in `onsubmit`. You have to use AJAX or something.

Comment: What you can do in this case is to construct json in your script before submitting then to insert this json into some hidden field.

Comment: You can create a hidden input (`<input type="hidden" name="json" id="json" />` in your form and fill it with `JSON.stringify(myData)` in `onsubmit` event.

Answer (score 1):

First construct an `output` which is an Array. Then use `JSON.strigify` to convert that to a `JSON` blob which will be part of the `ajax` call.

Also you cannot return data which is modified which is part of the form elements, you need to resort to making explicit `ajax` calls from JS.